# How to retrieve 3 latest records from 3 different category?

Tags: mysql, sql

Like i have table like below:

[image]

Is it possible to get three posts from three category? Please help me.

Comment: 3 records per category or 1 record per category?

Comment: three lastest posts per category? required result would be good ...

Comment: @Harshil 1 record per category.

Comment: Perfectly possible. If you’re still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: For category 4, which post should be displayed? Post 11 or Post 5?

Comment: @Harshil should be Post 5. However, I had mistaken for the last record its title should be Post 12, not Post 5.

Comment: if i've to return a random number of record for any certain 3 categories. suppose i want to return one record of the first category, then the category will return 2 records and the third one will return three records then what will be the query.

Comment: TOO BROAD??? Really??

Comment: yes . i need this @Harshil .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take the last time stamp per category -- using `max` and `group by` -- order them by that time stamp in descending order and take the top three with `limit`. Finally join this result with the original records using a join condition on `id` so you will not get more than three results, even when there are ties on the time stamp, and output those.

`tst` is the table name here:

```
select     tst.*
from       tst
inner join (
            select   category, 
                     max(time_stamp) time_stamp,
                     max(id) id
            from     tst
            group by category
            order by 2 desc
            limit    3
           ) as topthree
        on topthree.id = tst.id;
```

See it run on [rextester](http://rextester.com/XCQ59486)

Comment: **Thanks, Sir**. it's Worked!.

Comment: Sir, I've a question that if i've to return a random number of record for any certain 3 categories. suppose i want to return one record of the first category, then the category will return 2 records and the third one will return three records then what will be the query. Please, sir...

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve latest post per category use

```
 select p.*
 from posts p
 join (
    select category, max(time_stamp) maxts
    from posts
    group by p.category
 ) t on p.category = t.category and p.time_stamp = t.maxts
```

another solution is to use dependent subquery, however, it can be less efficient:

```
 select p.*
 from posts p
 where p.time_stamp = (
    select max(p2.time_stamp)
    from posts p2
    where p2.category = p.category
 )
```

Comment: **group by p.category** not allow. it showing Unknown column 'p.category' in 'group statement' . it should be posts.category, right..? However, Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display 1 record for the 3 categories with the latest `time_stamp`, following query will get the job done:

```
select *from
table
where (id,category,time_stamp) in (select
                                max(id),category,max(time_stamp)
                                from table
                                group by category)
group by category
order by time_stamp desc
limit 3
;
```

[Click here for Updated Demo](http://rextester.com/GDR82850)

Hope it helps!

Comment: No, it doesn't help.

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Please check the demo and try the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks. it's working :)

Comment: @App Glad to know. Kindly mark it as answer and/or upvote it.

Comment: @Harshil, I see my rextester script was useful to you -- you even kept the same timestamps :P

Comment: @trincot Yes...that was useful. Thank you.

Comment: @App I've updated my answer based on your comment. Please try it out.

Comment: Yeah, it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Following sql (MySQL) query that gives latest record of each category:

```
select id,title,category,time_stamp from
  (
     select id,title,category,time_stamp, 
            @cat_rank:=if(@prev_cat=category,@cat_rank+1,1) as 
            cat_rank,@prev_cat:=category
     from t_post,(select @cat_rank:='',@prev_cat:='')t 
          order by category,time_stamp desc

   )temp where cat_rank=1 ;
```

If you need only 3 categories, then limit the result by 3.