# How to get random number of latest records from different certain categories and order by categories?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've a table like below-

[image]

I want to one latest record from category 1, two from category 2, and three from category 4 and repeat this order. Result like below

[image]

Comment: Are your before and after pictures swapped?  And what do you mean by "repeat this order"?

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes.it has swappped!

Comment: I think this should be achieved programmatically (using php,java etc) rather than using sql

Comment: @Harshil yes. if there any possibility ..?

Comment: What is the purpose behind doing this task?

Comment: A client wants to show their news in such order.  it's very ridiculous!

Answer (score 0):

For your proposed output, you can do:

```
(select t.*
 from t
 where category = 'category 1'
 order by time_stamp desc
 limit 1
) union all
(select t.*
 from t
 where category = 'category 2'
 order by time_stamp desc
 limit 2
) union all
(select t.*
 from t
 where category = 'category 4'
 order by time_stamp desc
 limit 3
)
order by category, time_stamp desc;
```

For 3 known categories, `union all` is probably the simplest approach in MySQL.

Comment: The categories are not known. It is given in Op's previous question that he wants 3 categories with latest `max (time_stamp)` from all the available categories. Hence, the answer of that ques is Category 4,2 and 1. But this can be change in future. Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988030/how-to-retrieve-3-latest-records-from-3-different-category

Comment: Yes, i knew it. but i want to use this set of result order repeat again is it possible..?

Comment: @Harshil . . . If the OP has a question about a different set of categories, the OP should ask *another* question.  This question is pretty clearly about exactly three categories.

Comment: However, guys both questions have different scope.